# Is my implementation of insertion Sort correct?

Tags: c, insertion-sort, cs50

This is my first question on stack overflow. I have just started my journey in the world of programming through CS50. My code for insertion sort in C is a little different from what the instructor's pseudocode suggested. I just wish to know if the following code is correct and how can I make it better? Thanks alot.

```
int arr[6] = {23, 42, 4, 16, 8, 15};

for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)          // Iterating over the unsorted portion of array.
{
    int element = arr[i];           // This is the first element of the unsorted portion.
    int temp = -1;
    for(int j = i-1; j >= 0 && element < arr[j]; j--)   // Iterating over the unsorted portion of array from right to left.
    {
        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
        temp = j;
    }

    if(temp != -1)                 // If temp does not change, the element is already sorted.
    {
        arr[temp] = element;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler lol thanks for the reply anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Congrats, your code does work.

The first way to seeing this is putting this code in a function, like `main()`, and printing every element in order after running the algorithm. If the result is NOT what you expected, then it certainly isn't working, however, the contrary is not true. But if you pass the first try, you should start testing your code against other cases, especially corner cases.

Another helpful option here is using GDB, a debugger that can display the entire array at every step your code takes, especially the one implemented on CS50 IDE, which is actually very pleasing to watch.

Also, HackerRank's [challenges](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertionsort1) on [insertion sort](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insertionsort2) might help you out learning this. Other than that, good luck with your course, hope you enjoy!

Comment: Thanks mate! will definitely check it out. And yeah that debugger is sweet!